# Error: DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter using DataTables Server-side AJAX

Tags: php, json, datatables

**Intro**
I am doing a server-side datatables.net json plug-in.

**Error**
As soon as I try to add my last and 6th column `<th>Action,` I get this error message:

> "DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter
>   '6' for row 0, column 6. For more information about this error, please
>   see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

I have had this error message before and know what it generally means. But why it is trying to pull data from the database? I never used a `$subdata[]=$row[6];` I even watched a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCB2BHCVSjs. Also, when you click ok on the error message, the table loads as completely normal (with the exception of no button). 
**Index.php:**

```
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Updated</th>
<th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </table>

<?php
$records = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees");
$totalData= $records->num_rows;
$totalFiltered=$totalData;
$data=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) { 
    $subdata=array();
    $subdata[]=$row[0]; //id
    $subdata[]=$row[1]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[2]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[3]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[4]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[5]; 
      $subdata[]='<button></button>'; 
    $data[]=$subdata;
}

$requestData= $_REQUEST;
```

**Server.php**

```
 $json_data = array(
                      "draw" => intval(isset($_GET['draw'])), 
                      "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ), 
                      "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
                      "data"            => $data //How To Retrieve This Data
                     );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  
    ?>

$table = 'employees';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'date',     'dt' => 4 ),
     array( 'db' => 'updated',     'dt' => 5 ),

);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'id3741634_username',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'db'   => 'id3741634_database',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) { 
    $subdata['id']=$row['id']; //id
    $subdata['first']=$row['first']; //first
    $subdata['last']=$row['last']; //last
    $subdata['position']=$row['position']; //position
    $subdata['date']=$row['date']; //date
    $subdata['updated']=$row['updated']; //updated
    $subdata['button']='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>'; 
    $data[]=$subdata;
}

$requestData= $_REQUEST;
$json_data = array(
                  "draw" => intval(isset($_GET['draw'])), 
                  "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ), 
                  "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
                  "data"            => $data //How To Retrieve This Data
                 );

json_encode($json_data);  
?>
```

Comment: Do not think it worked. But I will try again on an earlier basic edition I had (theoretically the problem could be something else but your code could be right).

Comment: Well interesting. Your code works up until the time where you add the HTML <th Action.  So your method could work if we figure out what is wrong with my HTML or server.php script? Maybe I should post my server.php

Comment: @ScottSchmidt issue fixed?

Comment: Not exactly. Your code does the exact same as mine with the same error. As soon as a <th> action </th> 7th column is added, the error message pops up.  But your code did not make things worse (if that makes sense)

Comment: I think the issue is the computer sees 7 columns in the JSON but only 6 in the database so it gets confused at first. But then realizes it is not sending any data to the 7th colunn. Or something like that...

Comment: Could you pls. also show the HTML/JS to create the table?

Comment: Cant remember if I did:  array( 'db' => 'updated',     'dt' => 5 )   array( 'db' => 'action',   'dt' => 6 ).  I bet that might be the issue. You probably do not need the 6th action column in the server.php. I will login my site soon and check. On my phone right now.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_5vdEUKNGOM  Found a 2nd video that basically did the same thing as the other video and myself. I did not have the dt->action for the 6th column. I do not think it is needed (did not work either way).

Comment: Might have to use defaultContent from: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent